# Error: use of non-static data member

Tags: c++

[image]

This is the code in my class.h file that is causing me the problem. For some reason my functor can't access the master vector by giving me 10 counts of this error (1 for each use of master in the functor):

[image]

Any help would be wonderful, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: I wonder what made you prefer upload a screenshot over putting the actual code. Please, put code, not photos of it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile with support for C++11 (or later).
Up to C++11 in a nested class / struct you can use only type names, static members, and enumerators from the enclosing class.

See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

Answer (score 0):

The `previousComp` structure have no `master` member. You need an instance of the object(s) where `master` is a member variable to access it.

This can be done by having a reference to the class that `previousComp` is nested in, and using it. Like

```
struct previousComp
{
    ContainingClass const& object_;

    previousComp(ContainingClass const& object)
        : object_(object)
    {}

    bool operator()(...)
    {
        // Use object_.master here
    }
};
```

Pass `*this` to the constructor when creating the (temporary) instance of the structure.